# I want to copy data to another sheets after filter and sort

Tags: excel, vba, database

```
Sub FilterSortAndCopyData()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim sourceDataRange As Range
    Dim destinationRange As Range
    
    ' Set the source and destination worksheets
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your source sheet's name
    Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' Change to your destination sheet's name
    
    ' Set the source data range
    Set sourceDataRange = wsSource.Range("A1:D10") ' Adjust the range as needed
    
    ' Apply filter to show only "East" region
    sourceDataRange.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="East"
    
    ' Sort filtered data by "Amount" in descending order
    With sourceDataRange
        .AutoSort Field:=3, Order:=xlDescending ' Assuming "Amount" is in column 3
    End With
    
    ' Copy filtered and sorted data to destination sheet
    Set destinationRange = wsDestination.Range("A1")
    sourceDataRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy destinationRange
    
    ' Turn off the filter
    sourceDataRange.AutoFilter
    
End Sub
```

```
Sub FilterSortAndCopyData()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim sourceDataRange As Range
    Dim destinationRange As Range
    
    ' Set the source and destination worksheets
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your source sheet's name
    Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' Change to your destination sheet's name
    
    ' Set the source data range
    Set sourceDataRange = wsSource.Range("A1:D10") ' Adjust the range as needed
    
    ' Apply filter to show only "East" region
    sourceDataRange.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Eas
```

This my problem

Comment: It appears the second code is missing some lines. Please edit your question (find the [Edit] button/link beneath the tags of your question) and explain in detail what the problem is and what you are asking about that problem.

Comment: The second code block is the same as the first half of the first code block. We're you intending to include some other code? Please fix this and explain what your actual problem is that you want help with. Does your code not do what you expect (in which case, what should it do and what does it do?) or does it error (in which case, what error number, what error description and on which line does the error happen)?

Answer (score 0):

your problem seems to be that you're trying to use ".AutoFilter" to sort.

Use .Sort instead:

```
Sub FilterSortAndCopyData()
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
Dim sourceDataRange As Range
Dim destinationRange As Range

' Set the source and destination worksheets
Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your source sheet's name
Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' Change to your destination sheet's name

' Set the source data range
Set sourceDataRange = wsSource.Range("A1:D10") ' Adjust the range as needed

' Apply filter to show only "East" region
sourceDataRange.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="East"

' Apply filter to descend
sourceDataRange.Sort Key1:=Range("C1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

' Copy filtered and sorted data to destination sheet
Set destinationRange = wsDestination.Range("A1")
sourceDataRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy destinationRange

' Turn off the filter
sourceDataRange.AutoFilter

End Sub
```